# Raphael paper editing

Tags: jquery, raphael

I have posted a similar question before. I need to reuse a raphael paper in my page. I have multiple paper objects on a single page with some objects on each. In case of my previous question i needed to clear the paper and add different objects. I managed to do that by emptying the div and giving it as the first argument to Raphael paper creation. Now I have a problem as i am showing only a hover rect on another object of the paper. There are multiple papers in my page. Since I am reusing the variable for papers it is possible that it contains the wrong paper. In such case my hover is shown on that paper! For this I need to ensure that my hover handler picks up the proper paper. I can get the div for which I have created the paper but I cannot retrieve the paper i assigned to it!!
Please help me with this, Any suggestions are welcome.
Kavita

Comment: some code or example would be appreciated and make it easier for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is from you or not (these look like two different 'kavita'), but the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908242/raphael-paper-with-id) may help.

Comment: Yup, also noticed he is an unregistered user, so he probably isn't getting notified of answers to his questions. Also, may be having trouble finding his own questions from previous sessions...